# same column name in variable columns when pivot

Tags: c#, sql, pivot

```
price   c_melli cost_teacher
150000  5099572650  1         
170000  5099572650  1         
170000  5099572650  1         
150000  0015601218  1         
170000  0015601218  1         
200000  0015601218  1         
200000  0015601218  2         
200000  0015601218  2         
200000  0015601218  1 

    declare @cols nvarchar(max)
    declare @q nvarchar(max)
    select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(tblcity.cost_teacher)
            FROM tblCity where cost_teacher<>0
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')
    set @q=
    'select teacher_id,' +@cols+' from
    (select city1.teacher_id,cost_teacher,price from
    [dbo].[tblSessionPrice] join
    (select * from tblCity )city1  on
    [dbo].[tblSessionPrice].[id]=city1.    [cost_student])as s 
    PIVOT
    (
    SUM(price)
    FOR [cost_teacher] IN ('+ @cols+')
    )as pivottable'

    execute(@q)
    and same for count aggregate function

result is

    teacher_id  1         2         
    0015601218  720000  400000
    5099572650  490000  NULL

and 

    teacher_id  1       2         
    0015601218  4   2
    5099572650  3   0
```

because of variable columns when pivot i can not use alias name for tabel's columns.
i want to join this result but because same column name i can not.
is any way to do it befor or after pivot????

please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about declaring 2 @cols :

1. one for column name that you use for `IN PIVOT`
2. second identical but with as aliases for `select` statement

With this for PIVOT

```
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(tblcity.cost_teacher)
        FROM tblCity where cost_teacher<>0
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

With this one in SELECT

```
select @colsWithAliases = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(tblcity.cost_teacher + ' as Col' + tblcity.cost_teacher)
        FROM tblCity where cost_teacher<>0
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
```

Like this :

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)
declare @colsWithAliases nvarchar(max)
declare @q nvarchar(max)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(tblcity.cost_teacher)
        FROM tblCity where cost_teacher<>0
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
select @colsWithAliases = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(tblcity.cost_teacher + ' as Col' + tblcity.cost_teacher)
        FROM tblCity where cost_teacher<>0
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
set @q=
'select teacher_id,' +@colsWithAliases +' from
(select city1.teacher_id,cost_teacher,price from
[dbo].[tblSessionPrice] join
(select * from tblCity )city1  on
[dbo].[tblSessionPrice].[id]=city1.    [cost_student])as s 
PIVOT
(
SUM(price)
FOR [cost_teacher] IN ('+ @cols+')
)as pivottable'

execute(@q)
```

Comment: in both pivot query i have same columns

Comment: I Edited my answer, please have a look